# Java 11 + Oracle Forms-Standalone Launcher + 125%-Zoom = blurry application

Tags: java, zooming, java-11, oracleforms

After we switched from Java 8 to Java 11 with our Oracle Forms + Reports-Application, the GUI-font appears quite blurry when zoomed to 125% or 150%. For testing we switched back and replaced Java 11 with Java 8 and the application appeared fine when zoomed. How to fix it with Java 11?

We already tried the solutions we found online but nothing worked: Starting Java 11 with -Dsun.java2d.ddscale=true has no effect. Another possible solution would be to adjust the default DPI awareness mode of our application but we have no clue how and where to put a manifest file.

Any ideas?

Comment: What font specifically did you have a problem with? Did you try switching to another font on Java 11? Maybe the font is not supported on Java 11 and it is being replaced to some default font that doesn't zoom well.

Comment: Hmm... what do you know?  I found this on the web that kind of supports my suspicion: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3547024/default-font-forms-6i

Comment: @hfontanez: You're right, switching to another font partly works. But if we changed fonts througout the entire app, this woud be a huge workload. Do you know where to modify/add fonts to Java SE 11.0.12 and where to look for the same thing in Java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous Java bugs filed against this and similar issues.  Unfortunately, the exact cause has yet to be identified mostly because a good (Java) test case has not been provided to the Java team.

That said, some improvements have been made in newer Java versions.  Also, various combinations of these Java switches have claimed to offer some help. Which one is right for you will depend on the exact issue.

```
-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true

-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=true

-Dsun.java2d.autoScaleThreshold=1.5

-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0
```

If you decide to contact Oracle Support, refer to bug 31589993.  However, I would suggest testing with newer Java versions first.  The latest supported with Forms 12.2.1.4 is 17.0.2

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows

Comment: Thanks a lot: -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0 works for us with Java SE 11.0.12. However we'll think about updating.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is most likely the result of an unsupported font in Java 11. So, the best way to fix this is to switch to a supported font. The hard task is to switch to a font that look similar. Since I do not know which font is the culprit, I can't tell you which one to use that is supported on Java 11. You could "Google" it.

To learn more about default fonts in Java, read these articles

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html
2. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/intl/font-configuration-files.html#GUID-48F5ADDD-FB48-461D-8F26-9805DFB783CD

You may have to reach out to Oracle Forms support if the problem can't be solved through conventional ways. For example, for Swing apps, in order to change the default font, you have to modify the loaded `LookAndFeel` of the application.